# How to identify the pronouns to use for a single-author when citing them?

Tags: publications, citations, journals, authorship

I am writing a paper and want to cite an author's work. I don't know the authors pronouns and while I could go by pictures I find of the author online, I cannot find their pronouns anywhere.

I can always write "Author (YEAR) wrote ..." but to mix things up in a whole paragraph I write on author's work, I wanted to use a pronoun. But I don't know which pronoun. (I am not familiar enough with the language of the name either).

By now I think it should become common courtesy to indicate single-author's preferred/used pronouns directly on the publication. If the pronoun is not indicated, please tell me how to work around?

Comment: Check the guidelines for authors of the journal to which you plan to submit your paper.  It may be that the journal has a policy on this.

Comment: No there is nothing on that, I checked it. It’s an Elsevier journal - seems like many of them have the same guidelines

Comment: Welcome to Academia StackExchange! Given the slightly demanding tone in your last paragraph, I think it is worthwhile to remark that your perception is probably a bit biased. The concept of announcing one's pronouns seems to be mainly a thing in English speaking countries. Maybe there are also a few further countries where this is common, but it's far from universal. Just as one data point, in STEM in Germany, it is very uncommon to announce one's pronouns. So if you are citing people from various countries, you will quite often find the situation that they have not announced their pronouns.

Comment: So it’s basically something I thought was universal and not specific to certain areas of the world. I just don’t wanna be an asshole.

Comment: Well I have multiple paragraphs on the work of this author I heavily criticise (also a reason why I wanna be super correct!) and I just want to have a bit of variety in the sentence structure. If mostly is: work shows x (author, year). Just some variety and it’s like also a trope that is in this authors work and the literature has not adequately criticised yet.

Comment: @canIchangethis: Well, maybe it's a bit safer to replace "specific to certain areas of the world" with "depending on the area of the world and also on the specific academic field". For instance, the reason why I explicity mentioned STEM when referring to Germany is that such language issues can sometimes be quite differently perceived in various fields (think of e.g. engineering compared to gender studies). So my comment was not meant as advice on how to act in your situation; I just wanted to make you aware that announcing one's pronouns is not as universal as you might have thought.

Comment: (@canIchangethis: Oh, by the way: if you use an expression like "@JonDoe" in a comment, than John Doe is notified about your comment. This facilitates communication if you respond to a particular comment.)

Comment: Thanks @JochenGlueck I totally understood ur comment as such. And thanks for the reminder to the @ function

Comment: @canIchangethis Just as a note, the fact to you find need to use personal pronouns may be sign that you are making your criticism too personal. Criticize the work, not the author. In doing so, you will find that you mostly need pronouns to refer back to the work (ie it), rather than personal pronouns referring back to the author.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This does not directly answer the title question, but instead of using personal pronoun, in many cases you can achieve the desired variation by using terms like "the paper", "the study", and so on (in addition to "the author" that atom44 suggests, which I also find quite common).

This might be preferable in itself (not simply as a work around). After all, the subject of discussion is usually the work, not the author, and the "Author (year)" is commonly understood to refer to the work. (For example, the Chicago Manual of Style specifically states that "an author-date citation is a form of bibliographic shorthand that corresponds to a fully cited work; it does not refer to a person.")

Comment: Oh, oh, this is probably the answer!

Answer (score 7):

In English, you can always use the (singular) pronoun *they* when referring to people of unknown/unclear gender. See the following (fictional) example:

> **Smith** (2014) finds that children under the age of 3 prefer 3-wheeled bicycles. **Their** research also shows a preference for the color green.

Comment: Oh absolutely, I can. But what if that person really wants their she/her or he/his pronouns? Just imagine they are a trans-female or trans-male (as an example!!).

Comment: @canIchangethis I would believe that most people who would absolutely want to be adressed by a specific pronoun would be the few ones who might state them. And most people will probably prefer a gender neutral approach to being misgendered.

Comment: The thing is, in m field of research I have never seen anyone state their pronouns (especially not on any publications) that’s why I want to make sure I don’t gender people wrong. And yes, imho, using they instead of another pronoun is also a form of misgendering, right?

Comment: In English, the "they" pronoun is not specifically for unknown gender, it is also grammatically correct where the gender is known and binary.

Comment: @IanSudbery I know. AFAIK, is can be both: a pronoun used to adress a person of unknown gender and a pronoun to adress non-binary persons. I see it as a from of umbrella pronoun that includes everyone, and while most people rather specify their gender more closely (e.g. her/him) it is as if I would call an animal an animal, and some animals might say: but I am a giraffe, others might be content to staying a not-further disclosed animal. But calling any of them an animal is not wrong.

Comment: Sursula, I wished it were like that. I would be fine if they were a default one could always go back to. But I thought that’s not how it is. See also the comments under the question telling me that pronoun disclosures don’t happen in some parts of the world.

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be problematic to require (or even encourage) authors to include preferred pronouns in their papers. Some people would want to leave this ambiguous, for example to avoid any real/perceived bias in the review process, etc.

I think you have a few options:

1. Research the author and see if you can find an interview/bio (which are often written in 3rd person) -- you seem to have already done this
2. Ask colleagues in the field if they know, they may have met this person at a conference for example.
3. Use 'they/their' as others have suggested
4. Use 'the author'  (  Surname (1992) set out to prove that the world is flat. However, the author was unsuccessful because ... ).
5. Email and ask them. If the gender of the name is ambiguous in English they have probably been misgendered before and would appreciate the attempt to get it right.

Comment: Jeah I think the addition to a preferred citation could come far after the review process, like in production stage.

Comment: But besides that, I am very grateful for the suggestions and as you said I have done that

Comment: Upvoted. I particularly like that you mentioned the option to simply ask the author. "Just ask" is suprisingly often a surprisingly simple and efficient solution to a problem. :-)